How to create VS Code extension that parses string (in Python) and provide more information when hover them
I would like to create a VS Code extension that will parse text on the current active editor, will use regex to extract specific strings that conform to feature flag we use and will then query another service to present to the developer the current state of that feature flag.
I'm trying to understand which VS Code extension points can be used to present such information.
I've found decorator example which is doing the part of extracting the interesting part from the text but it only highlight it.
I would like to take that further and present more details about that feature flag using tooltip, sub-view (I'm not sure how it is called), by hovering or any other way.

Have you looked at hoverProviders?

Yes, I think decorator are good solution for my needs. I’ll check hoverProvider as well

After some research I've found that using CodeLens can be the best solution for my needs to present information inline with the code.
